# How to use Qxt libraries on PyQt?

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, libqxt

First of all, please excuse my bad English. I hope you guys understand what I am saying.

I have developed the server and client system. The server side is based on **Qt**, and the client side is based on **PyQt**. (I wanted to build the client based on **Qt** too, but there were no other choices because of several issues).

To communicate each other, I use `QLocalSocket`. But it is not enough. I want to use `Signal` and `Slot` via network.

Fortunately, I found out `QxtRPCPeer`. It exactly supports what I want to do. However, unfortunately, I couldn't find how to use `QxtRPCPeer` on Python (PyQt).

I tried to use `SIP`, but I have no experiences about it and there is no enough time to study `SIP` by myself.

I hope there is another way to implement signal/slot via network between **Qt** and **PyQt**. I await for your response, and keep studying it too.

Comment: Check out [http://code.google.com/p/pyqxt/](http://code.google.com/p/pyqxt/) It gives the python bindings for libqxt. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Marcus. The pyqxt project seems to be pure vapourware.

Comment: Lacking python bindings, it might not be too hard to code up something in python using JSON-RPC or whatever. You just need to map objects and their slots to URL's, and marshall some data. JSON-parsers are available in python easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grepping through both pyqt and pyside source code shows neither project has bindings for Qxt.

There's a project on google code, no code published yet: http://code.google.com/p/pyqxt/

Bindings with very narrow focus, only global shortcut: https://github.com/jmatt/pygs

I'm afraid as it stands now, you can't have what you want.

If it is acceptable, write rpc shim in C++ and wrap it in a Python module.